# How to know if a cookies is valid?

Tags: session, cookies

According to Wikipedia, cookies are :

> Cookies were designed to be a reliable mechanism for websites to
>   remember stateful information (such as items added in the shopping
>   cart in an online store) or to record the user's browsing activity
>   (including clicking particular buttons, logging in, or recording which
>   pages were visited in the past).

Session ID is:

> a session identifier, session ID or session token is a piece of data
>   that is used in network communications (often over HTTP) to identify a
>   session, a series of related message exchanges.

My question is when the client send the cookies to the server the, how the server know it is a valid cookies? Does the server store a copy of the cookies to compare with the cookies sent by the client, so if they match then it is valid, otherwise not?
And how the server store the cookies of all the clients, are they in a database or in memory? If in database, what is the key to search the database, is it session ID?

Comment: The server doesn't store cookies. The cookies are not valid or invalid, they are just data that the browser sends to the server and the server responds to them. However session ids are stored on the server, along with data associated with that session. In PHP they are stored in a file with a name matching the session id.

Comment: If there is no verified mechanism, and you send a fake cookies, how the server know that?

Comment: You can send arbitrary cookies to the server and the server doesn't know who created them. However the cookie could also contain a session id (I forgot to mention this in my comment). The session id is very long and computational hard to predict (it is like a password). When the server recieves the cookie containing a session id, it matches it to the session id stored on the server.

Comment: The server stores data associated with this session id.

Comment: I've got it. Thank you.